# How to read the result of of posthoc kruskal dunn test?

Tags: r, distributions, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

How to read the result of of posthoc kruskal dunn test? Specifically, what do the values in the table below tell me?

I have 6 treatments and I first did a Kruskal-Wallis test to confirm that the groups' distributions were dissimilar from one another and the aggregate dataset. I then used posthoc.kruskal.dunn's test to see which groups were dissimilar from one another, and which were not.

Its result was [image]

Comment: Why no correction for multiple testing?

Comment: @MichaelM                                                

I used this code:                                           kruskal.test(Treatment~DayFive, data=B)
B$Treatment <- as.factor(B$Treatment)
posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(x=DayFive, g=B$Treatment, p.adjust.method="none")

and this was what I got.